# Android Alert Dialog place Edit Text Before List View

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog, alert

I'm Creating an alert dialog with a list view and edit text and i have succeeded in that , however i want the edit text to appear first then the list view but the output is the opposite.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    builderSingle.setTitle("Select Item");
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(1); // 1 is for vertical orientation
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    ll.addView(input);
            builderSingle.setNegativeButton("cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    builderSingle.setAdapter(adapter,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        }
            });

    builderSingle.setView(ll);
    AlertDialog alert = builderSingle.create();
    alert.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

For compound views I'd recommend coding the layout in XML then inflating and setting it in the dialog builder code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   
mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
// My dialog is a separate class so getting your context may be easier.
View custView = inflater.inflate(R.custom_layout, null);`

...

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
builder.setTitle(title);
builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_pro);
builder.setView(custView);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be default behavior. Maybe you should take more control over all of this by creating your own ListView in your layout so you can position everything more predictably.